# Keeping the radio button checked after cached using JSON

Tags: jquery, json, caching

Here is my Function code:

```
var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("input[name='GLOVE']").click(function() {

        jQuery('input[type="radio"][data-default="1"]').each(function() {
            var key = jQuery(this).attr("name");
            var value = jQuery("input[name='" + key + "']:checked").val() 
                      ? jQuery("input[name='" + key + "']:checked").val() 
                      : null;
            if (key != "GLOVE") {
                checkboxValues[this.id] = value;
            }
        });

        localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
        jQuery.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
            if (key != "option-5b2089bd80038" || key != "cboption-5b2089bd9d11b") {
                console.log(key + " " + value);
                jQuery("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
            }
        });
    });
});


jQuery.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
    if (key != "option-5b2089bd80038") {
        console.log(key + " " + value);
        jQuery("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
    }
});
```

The Value are already saving in the console but the Buttons are not remaining to be checked after cached.

in this part I use condition logic in product builder (wordpress), so there are two main button, front and back, when I click "front" these colors will show up (also in back), so the thing is when I pick a color and go to "back" the color should stay when I click the "Front" again. in the condition logic I made that if I click "Front" the components of Back will be hiden and vice versa.

here is the sample image of the buttons:

[image: screenshot]]

PROBLEM: when i cached or refresh the page the buttons are back to its default color (purple). how to keep the buttons (example i clicked the blue) checked to remain after cached?

**UPDATE**

the problem already solved but the reload is limited to twice. ( when you pick a color then reload it stay but when you reload it like twice/three times it goes back to default)

```
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('input[type="radio"][data-default="1"]').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).removeAttr("data-default");
        });


        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
                jQuery(this).removeAttr("data-default");
                if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
                    jQuery(this).attr("data-default", "1");
                }

            });
        });
    }, 18000);
};
```

do you know the reason why it is limited?

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? Have you used the browser's developer tools to inspect the contents of your localStorage at different times?

Comment: there are no errors sir, its just that the it is limited to 2/3 loads that the buttons are checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered:

```
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
          jQuery('input[type="radio"][data-default="1"]').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).removeAttr("data-default");
            });


            jQuery(function(){
              jQuery('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
                if (jQuery(this).is(':checked'))
                {
                jQuery(this).attr("data-default" , "1");
                }

           });
        });
    }, 18000);
};
```

just removed the `jQuery(this).removeAttr("data-default");`

**thank you for the efforts!**